# Try running code x times and if it fails x times raise exception

Tags: python, try-catch

There is a code that randomly raises an error.

When the code fails, I want to rerun it, but if it fails x times I want to raise a custom error.

Is there a proper way to do it in Python?

#

I am thinking the following but it doesn't seem to be the best.

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass


try:
    for i in range(x):
        try:
            some_code()
            break
        except:
            pass
except:
    raise MyException("Check smth")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an infinite loop that will break on success, and count the errors in the `except` block:

```
max_errors = 7

errors = 0
while True:
    try:
        run_code()
        break
    except ExceptionYouWantToCatch:  # You shouldn't use a bare except:
        errors += 1
        if errors > max_errors:
            raise MyException
```

Another way to do it:

```
max_errors = 7


for run in range(max_errors):
    try:
        run_code()
        break
    except ExceptionYouWantToCatch:  # You shouldn't use a bare except:
        pass
else:  # will run if we didn't break out of the loop, so only failures
    raise MyException
```

Comment: What you proposed in your question would run the code again even if it doesn't fail, which is not what you want according to your description. So, yes. ;)

Comment: I added another solution. A bit shorter, maybe a bit less explicit though. Make your choice!

Comment: Ok ok thanks! I haven't noticed that it is missing a break, I am adding this. I am doing the comparison between having 2 variables, a while and an if instead of 1 for and one try-except. Do you think that this comparison is wrong?

Comment: Choose something that you find clear and easy to understand, the rest are details here.

Comment: The alternative way looks more clear to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
for i in range(x):
    retries = <how many times you want to try> 
    while retries: # This could be while 1 since the loop will end in successful run or with exception when retries run out. 
        try:
            some code
            break # End while loop when no errors
         except:
            retries =- 1
            if not retries:
                raise MyException("Check smth")
```

Comment: This is not what the OP expects. The code should be run agai **if** it fails.

Comment: And now I was thinking that your firest for-loop was part of your code. If you want to run the code just once but try multiple times in case of fails, you can just drop it off.